# How to obtain the latest non-null values for each column of rows with the same identifier?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Given a table like this:

```
+---------+-------+------+------+---------------------+
| user_id |   a   |  b   |  c   |          t          |
+---------+-------+------+------+---------------------+
|   10001 | one   |    2 | NULL | 2014-09-27 12:30:01 |
|   10002 | seven |    8 |    9 | 2020-09-27 12:30:02 |
|   10001 | four  | NULL |    6 | 2014-09-27 12:30:03 |
+---------+-------+------+------+---------------------+
```

I'd like to obtain the following:

```
+---------+-------+------+------+
| user_id |   a   |  b   |  c   |
+---------+-------+------+------+
|   10001 | four  |    2 |    6 |
|   10002 | seven |    8 |    9 |
+---------+-------+------+------+
```

This is, for each `user_id`, obtain a single row with the latest non-`NULL` value of each column.

My current attempt looks as follows:

```sql
WITH
  foo AS (
  SELECT
    10001 user_id,
    'one' a,
    2 b,
    NULL c,
    TIMESTAMP('2014-09-27 12:30:01') t,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    10002 user_id,
    'seven' a,
    8 b,
    9 c,
    TIMESTAMP('2020-09-27 12:30:02') t,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    10001 user_id,
    'four' a,
    NULL b,
    6 c,
    TIMESTAMP('2014-09-27 12:30:03') t,
    )
SELECT
  user_id,
  a,
  b,
  c
FROM
  foo s1
WHERE
  t = (
  SELECT
    MAX(t)
  FROM
    foo s2
  WHERE
    s1.user_id = s2.user_id)
ORDER BY
  user_id
```

But of course, this simply keeps the latest row per `user_id`, which is not what I need.

```
+---------+-------+------+---+
| user_id |   a   |  b   | c |
+---------+-------+------+---+
|   10001 | four  | NULL | 6 |
|   10002 | seven |    8 | 9 |
+---------+-------+------+---+
```

How do I replace `NULL`s with non-`NULL` values from older rows of that `user_id` (if existing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select distinct user_id, 
  first_value(a ignore nulls) over win a, 
  first_value(b ignore nulls) over win b, 
  first_value(c ignore nulls) over win c
from foo 
window win as (
  partition by user_id 
  order by t desc 
  rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following 
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you would like, and this is very non-optimal approach, but it is more or less strait forward, and (I hope) easy to understand:

```
with foo as (
  select 10001 user_id, 'one' a, 2 b, null c, timestamp('2014-09-27 12:30:01') t
    union all
  select 10002 user_id, 'seven' a, 8 b, 9 c, timestamp('2020-09-27 12:30:02') t
    union all
  select 10001 user_id, 'four' a, null b, 6 c, timestamp('2014-09-27 12:30:03') t
    union all 
  select 10003 user_id, 'five' a, null b, null c, timestamp('2014-09-27 12:31:03') t
    union all 
  select 10003 user_id, 'nine' a, 2 b, null c, timestamp('2014-09-27 12:31:04') t
    union all 
  select 10004 user_id, 'six' a, 6 b, null c, timestamp('2014-09-27 12:31:03') t
    union all 
  select 10004 user_id, 'seven' a, 6 b, 9 c, timestamp('2014-09-27 12:31:00') t
)
, b_table as (
  select 
    user_id
    , last_value(b) over(partition by user_id order by t desc) as last_b
  from foo
  where b is not null
)
, c_table as (
  select 
    user_id
    , last_value(c) over(partition by user_id order by t desc) as last_c
  from foo
  where c is not null
)
, full_table as (
  select 
    foo.user_id 
    , foo.a
    , b_table.last_b
    , c_table.last_c
   , foo.t
  from 
    foo 
      left outer join 
    b_table on foo.user_id = b_table.user_id 
      left outer join 
    c_table on foo.user_id = c_table.user_id   
)
select
  agg.full_table.*
from 
  (
    select
        user_id,
        array_agg(struct(full_table) order by t desc)[safe_offset(0)] agg
    from
        full_table
    group by
        user_id
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT 10001 user_id, 'one' a, 2 b, NULL c, TIMESTAMP('2014-09-27 12:30:01') t UNION ALL
  SELECT 10002 user_id, 'seven' a, 8 b, 9 c, TIMESTAMP('2020-09-27 12:30:02') t UNION ALL
  SELECT 10001 user_id, 'four' a, NULL b, 6 c, TIMESTAMP('2014-09-27 12:30:03') t UNION ALL 
  SELECT 10001 user_id, 'eight' a, NULL b, NULL c, TIMESTAMP('2014-09-27 12:33:03') t 

)
, ranking as (
select distinct user_id 
    , last_value(a IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY t) a 
    , last_value(b IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY t) b 
    , last_value(c IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY t) c
    , row_number() OVER (partition by user_id order by t desc) row_num
from sample_data 
)
select user_id
    , a
    , b
    , c 
from ranking
where row_num = 1
```

Last value will give you the last value in the defined window, in this case being by user ordered by the timestamp.